Constraint to enforce pairwise distinctness of values in two columns in table
I'm kind of stumped by a seemingly simple problem in Db design, but the more I think about about it, the more it twists my mind.
Let's say I have columns C1 and C2 in a table. How do I enforce that the pairing of values of C1 and C2 is pairwise disticnt? That is, a specific composite value for C1 and C2, say X and Y, can appear any number of times in the table, but once X/Y appears, you cannot have X/Z, or W/Y.
It seems such a simple constraint to model, but several hours of research still leaves with no solutions. I'm using PostgreSQL, but I guess the issue is probably db-agnostic. I explored partial indexes, but that feature seems too limited for my problem. Any ideas?
To put this in more context, my problem arises from trying to design a users table that maintains version history with the following columns:
 - internal_id (primary key, auto-generated number),
 - external_id (varchar, not null),
 - auth_id (varchar, not null, can be phone #, email address, etc),
 - display_name (varchar),
 - access_level (number, not null),
 - when_record_version_created (timestamp, not null),
 - when_record_version_expired (timestamp),
 - unique (external_id, when_record_version_created)

A record is valid from when_record_version_created to when_record_version_expired. This should basically work, but without enforcing the pairwise distinct relationship between external_id and auth_id, it would be possible to associate an auth_id with more than one external_id, which would corrupt the data.
The problem can also be expressed as: how do I setup a unique constraint on a column, where the uniqueness only applies within groups defined by distinct values of another column in the same table.

This is a typical case where denormalization makes your life more painful. Extract e.g. a table (pk, external_id, auth_id) with UNIQUE constraints on both those columns, use its pk as FK in the original table. If the performance cost of one PK join is unacceptable in your case, please tell us more about the nature of queries and performance constraints.

I'm having troubles parsing through your question. The example is really good, but can you state your requirements as they are related to the external id, auth id, and date ranges?

@burghardt: The problem can be expressed as: how to express a unique constraint on a column, that only applies within groups defined by distinct values of another column in the same table.

Obviously it's a complicated constraint for which you can't expect there to be a direct, built-in form of expression.
The way I'm reading it, it's that the pairing of X/Y can recur multiple times in your table, but once X and Y are yoked together at least once, then the two values individually cannot participate as members of any other different pairings.
What I'd suggest is that you need an auxiliary table that records existing pairings distinctly (i.e. once only), and have separate unique constraints on the C1 and C2 columns, as well as a primary key on C1+C2. Then to this auxiliary table, have a foreign key constraint on C1+C2 from your main table where the same pairings can appear multiple times.
In real-world databases though, I'd be very careful about such a level of complexity in the constraints. Beyond basics like PK enforcement (which defines what is usually the index of primary importance too), constraints are often much more suited to recording the schema details of read-only databases, or databases with a very minimal burden of ongoing changes (to both data and schema). My experience is that FK constraints are often recorded in the schema but not enforced. The use of triggers I would caution against even moreso.
They all have their appropriate uses, but the appropriateness is far less general than novice practitioners assume.
For database designs used for typical OLTP loads, it's often better to write stored procedures that perform the changes correctly, but also give you more control over the algorithm and control over how and when the constraint is enforced.
EDIT:
Just looking at some additional info you added since I first loaded the page, there are significant additional flaws here.
One thing, you should use a sequential number for your versions, not a timestamp. This is because sometimes changes can be made in short succession in one period/tick of the clock, or the hardware clock can be set back to re-synchronise it.
Often novice developers keep trying to fight this by increasing the resolution of the clock or using supposedly universal and monotonic schemes like UTC, but that is the wrong approach and it invariably proceeds from a welter of faulty assumptions.
Second thing, I would not bind a user irrevocably to one phone number or email address, because at some point for some users, this will have to change.

Even if I use a sequential number for the versions, I might still need to query for time ranges, and so the timestamp would still be needed. If I use TimeStampZ for example, shouldn't it solve most of the issues? Or maybe I could use composite foreign keys from fact tables that reference both the id and version number.
Also, with the suggestion not to bind a user irrevocably to one phone number or email address, I understand that. My table is just an example, to illustrate the question properly. With my actual database I am aware of your suggestion.

@prmph, based on what I've said, querying for time ranges (rather than sequence ranges) could be inaccurate, couldn't it?

While I agree with most of your answer, there's one exception: "One thing, you should use a sequential number for your versions, not a timestamp." That depends on your business context and the frequency of change, and should not go as general advice. For example, in data warehousing, it is absolutely common to use timestamps like validFrom and validBefore in a data vault.

The related question is what is the best practice for generating the version number in a distributed scenario, and is it a good idea to use both the external id and version number as a kind of composite foreign key in fact tables that reference the users table?

@prmph, you don't generate an unambiguous time-sequence of version numbers in distributed scenarios. They fundamentally require correspondence with a central authority. A system of clocks in which slave clocks are synchronised to a single master, is partly an attempt to create the necessary central authority, but these can only differentiate events to within a minimum resolution and a minimum skew, and in real-world systems these quantities are variable and their magnitude at times can be large beyond assumption.

@prmph, you might find this, and the links therein, very interesting reading:https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca.

@mtj, (sorry I think I somehow missed responding to your comment yesterday...) my advice would be not to do what you propose where you are (a) keeping versions of the same record, (b) assigning times to those versions automatically using the system clock, and (c) using the assigned times to determine the precedence/currency of each version. You can keep timestamps in addition to a sequence number, but the sequence number should be considered master, and as general advice a developer should treat timekeeping as a complicated subject. (1/2)

The reality of many common practices is that real-world computer software is riddled with faults of all kinds, and stored data riddled with hidden errors and falsehoods, so common practice should never be used on its own to justify the legitimacy or desirability of a particular approach. (2/2)
